# Grafana query variable regex replacement

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

Hello I'd like to create a variable with `label_value` and then replace the label by some regexp. The `value` should be entire string, the `text` should be only part which starts with uppercase (e.g. `ManualAllocationPolicy:pending`. I guess the regular expression is quite good, but it's not displayed as I want. What am I missing? Grafana version is `9.4.7`

[image: variable]

[image: select]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of the regex problem, then Grafana problem. Your application of alteration for regex is incorrect: in case of alteration only one of groups will be matched (`text` in your exact case).

To match same text multiple times you'll need to employ a trick: capturing groups inside of lookaheads.

Your regex will look like this: `^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z].*))(?<value>.+)`

For metric name

```
elasticsearch_sync_queue_lowerlevelgiberishManualAllocationPolicy:pending
```

It will produce two groups:

- text: `ManualAllocationPolicy:pending`
- value: `elasticsearch_sync_queue_lowerlevelgiberishManualAllocationPolicy:pending`

Demo of this regex matching online [here](https://regex101.com/r/90uBfu/2). Matched groups can be seen on the right panel.

Comment: wonderful...thanks. Would you be able to remove also the `:pending`? I've tried with `[^:]` but I've probably placed it at wrong position.

Comment: either [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oF70rG/1) is giving me false result with substitution or I'm doing it wrong

Comment: @bilak, if you want to remove `:pending` only from text use [`^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z][^:]*))(?<value>.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oF70rG/2).

Comment: I want to remove from both text and value.

Comment: @bilak, than regex from your link is correct. If may not see green background for group `text`, but it is still matched (look at the right panel.)

Comment: I've seen that in panel, but it doesn't work even in grafana. So there might be some issue.

Comment: @bilak, hm, looks like Grafana have problema with `:` in group `value`. Surround regex with `/`, like this `/^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z][^:]*))(?<value>[^:]+)/`, it should work (works for me with similar setup)

Comment: this returns just one result...idk what's wrong with grafana

Comment: so finally this works `^(?=.*?(?<text>[A-Z][^:]*))(?<value>.+)(:.*)`